# Gsutil generating python related error in git bash but runs in other terminals

Tags: python, gcloud, git-bash, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

gsutil is not working in git bash and is generating an error, I can use it in Windows terminal, cmd and Google cloud SDK shell

since it's generating issue addressing python I checked if python is installed properly or not
[in git bash gsutil shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrF6e.png)

[In windows terminal gsutil shows version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ldV4.png)

Any ideas on how can this be fixed ? and what must be the reason behind it ?

Comment: Why do you want using `gcloud` cli in git bash ?

Comment: 1) Your question lacks details to help you. 2) The problem is that Python cannot be found under Git Bash. This typically means a PATH problem. Is the Python location in the PATH? 3) How did you install the CLI and which options did you select? 4) Edit your question with more details.

Comment: Note: Your problem is not caused by Git Bash. It is most likely caused by how you installed and setup Python and the CLI.